# Findbugs assigning byte array value through parameter or clone()

Tags: java, arrays, findbugs

so for example I have this constructor

```
public Example(byte[] bytes) {
    this.bytes = bytes;
}
```

And after running FindBugs, it will say that I should consider cloning it instead... so I tried that and it eliminated the warning.

```
public Example(byte[] bytes) {
    this.bytes = bytes.clone();
}
```

However, I want to know if there are any implications, or negative side-effects to this kind of change. From my understanding, it also applies to all arrays, not just byte[].

Thanks

Comment: More memory usage and less performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible bug would be that if you reuse the array in the instance you'll couple it with the calling code, i.e. every change made to the array but outside that class might have side effects.

Example:

```
char[] chars = new char[]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z' };
Alphabet lower = new Alphabet( chars );

for( int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++ ) {
  chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase( chars[i] );
}
Alphabet upper = new Alphabet( chars );
```

If the array is reused inside `Alphabet` (i.e. not cloned) you might think that `lower` deals with lower case characters while it's really using the array whose elements have been replaced with their upper case counter part.

Thus in most cases it is safer to create a copy of the array, e.g. by calling `clone()` on it (there are other ways as well).

The downside to this are an increased memory usage (of course) and some performance cost for doing the copy - both of which might be negligible for a few small arrays but increase when the size and/or the number of arrays increases.

Another downside *might* be that the calling code could expect the array to be shared and creating a clone might break that. You'd have to check for that as well.

Comment: Thanks! I understood this more coz of the example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very generic situation - when you create an object that depends on some "outside" array or list - should that object simply re-use the existing reference; or do you need to create a copy of that input data?!

Re-using means: you don't spend CPU cycles on copy operations; and obviously, you re-use memory as well (one copy of things, instead of two, three, ...)

On the other hand: when you keep references, and somebody else updates that "external" thing ... all your objects that hold that reference might be affected as well.

In that sense: you should balance those two options mainly based on what is "best" from a design point of view. In general, many people nowadays tries to implement **immutable** classes/objects. Meaning: upon creation, the "content" of an object will never change again; in other words: if you want to go **immutable**, you have to turn to "defensive copying". But there are lot of things to gain from that.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to take a defensive copy, so that subsequent updates to the array don't write through to `Example` object. It also helps with garbage collection as you are not holding on to a reference to the array.

In terms of implications, you are potentially using more memory as you might end up storing the array twice.